# У меня двое внучек или две внучки?

Tags: грамотная-речь, количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

Как правильно: двое внучек или две внучки?

Answer (score 3):

**Две внучки.** Собирательные числительные не сочетаются с существительными ж. рода. Почему? Об этом спорили много, но таки не пришли к ясному и однозначному выводу.

**Два внука или двое внуков** - здесь можно выбирать. "Два внука" встречается чаще, так как количественное числительное только определяет число, а собирательное числительное подчеркивает совокупность предметов, рассматривает предметы как единую группу. Например: двое мальчиков заблудились в лесу.

Answer (score 0):

*Две внучки*. Это же женский род.

Answer (score 0):

Даже "двое внуков" выглядит плоховато, хотя и допустимо. Вот если бы четверо!